# Postfix: User unknown in virtual alias table

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

For some reason when I send an email from my self-hosted postfix server, it works, but can't receive due to this:

```
Nov  3 18:30:06 pi postfix/qmgr[31993]: CB178142FAB: from=<megver83@megver83.ga>, size=738, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  3 18:30:06 pi postfix/error[1173]: CB178142FAB: to=<megver83@megver83.ga>, orig_to=<megver83>, relay=none, delay=4.7, delays=4.7/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
Nov  3 18:30:06 pi postfix/error[1232]: D3CEC142FAD: to=<megver83@megver83.ga>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
Nov  3 18:30:07 pi postfix/qmgr[31993]: 0E1AC142FAB: from=<megver83@megver83.ga>, size=734, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  3 18:30:07 pi postfix/error[1173]: 0E1AC142FAB: to=<megver83@megver83.ga>, orig_to=<megver83>, relay=none, delay=4.9, delays=4.8/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
Nov  3 18:30:07 pi postfix/error[1232]: 1685A142FAD: to=<megver83@megver83.ga>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
Nov  3 18:34:37 pi postfix/error[1292]: BC405142FAB: to=<megver83@megver83.ga>, relay=none, delay=0.28, delays=0.27/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
Nov  3 19:11:39 pi postfix/qmgr[31993]: EDC14142FAB: from=<megver83@hyperbola.info>, size=1238, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  3 19:11:43 pi postfix/smtp[2064]: 3D67B142FAD: to=<megver83@hyperbola.info>, relay=spool.mail.gandi.net[217.70.184.6]:25, delay=3.8, delays=0.02/0.1/3.5/0.27, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host spool.mail.gandi.net[217.70.184.6] said: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [190.100.12.50] blocked using pbl.spamhaus.org; https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/190.100.12.50 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Nov  3 19:13:02 pi postfix/qmgr[31993]: 899D4142FAB: from=<megver83@hyperbola.info>, size=1256, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  3 19:13:02 pi postfix/error[1958]: 899D4142FAB: to=<megver83@megver83.ga>, relay=none, delay=0.26, delays=0.25/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
Nov  3 19:13:05 pi postfix/smtp[2064]: CA3A8142FAD: to=<megver83@hyperbola.info>, relay=spool.mail.gandi.net[217.70.184.6]:25, delay=2.3, delays=0.02/0/2.1/0.25, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host spool.mail.gandi.net[217.70.184.6] said: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [190.100.12.50] blocked using pbl.spamhaus.org; https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/190.100.12.50 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

I'm trying to send a mail from megver83@hyperbola.info to megver83@megver83.ga, but doesn't work. However, as I said, it works the other way around. This is my `postconf -n`

```
alias_database = $alias_maps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/bin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/bin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 134217728
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 134217728
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydomain = megver83.ga
myhostname = pi.megver83.ga
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
relay_domains = *
relayhost =
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/megver83.ga/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/megver83.ga/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = megver83.ga, eumela.ga, heckyel.ga
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
megver83.ga megver83.ga
megver83@megver83.ga megver83
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `5.1.1 User unknown in virtual alias table`

   - Check that your `/etc/postfix/virtual` has a `virtual_alias_maps` entry for `megver83@megver83.ga`, binding it to a local or foreign address, not to another virtual alias.
   - Remember to `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` in order to update the corresponding `.db`, as you are using `hash:` type database.
2. `5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [190.100.12.50] blocked using pbl.spamhaus.org;`

   - [Self-documenting](https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/190.100.12.50). Your IP is blocked using a DNS blacklist.
   - Avoid getting on such listings. For example, do not make your server an *open relay* using that `relay_domains = *` and apply suitable [relay and access control](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html). If you don't, you'll soon be blocked everywhere.

Comment: "Check that your /etc/postfix/virtual has a virtual_alias_maps entry for megver83@hyperbola.info" - But I want to send an email from that address to `megver83@megver83.ga`, because in that case I would have to add a thousand email addresses from ppl who tries to send me emails

Comment: Mixed them up. Corrected. The answer otherwise stays the same.

Comment: i missunderstood your answere, i have the same problem and the user is localy inside the machine, all users can send mails but nither the local net the mails delivers, allwais softbounced..., i never found an answere here....